# XAML: Update binding when changing DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a simple XAML file, it contains a Label whose Foreground property contains a binding:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Width="200" Height="100" >
    <Label Content="Sampletext" Foreground="{Binding Path=Color}" />
</Grid>
```

When I load the template and apply a DataContext the Foreground still has the default value.
Is it possible to get bound foreground value **without** rendering the Grid?

```
// Load template
string templatePath = "/WpfApplication1;component/Template.xaml";
Grid grid = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri(templatePath, UriKind.Relative)) as Grid;

// Set dataContext
grid.DataContext = new { Color = Brushes.Green };

// Foregound still has default value
var foreground = ((Label)grid.Children[0]).Foreground;
```

Project can be downloaded here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21096596/WpfApplication1.zip

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the anonymous type there?  Have you tried it without?

Comment: And... are you seeing any binding errors in the output window?

Comment: There is no error. The question is, whether it es possible to get bound foreground color without rendering the grid. When I render the grid everything is fine.

Comment: Aah, I see what you mean, now.  And no, I don't think it is: data binding wouldn't make sense to be evaluated until the control is rendered.  However, you should be able to render the control offscreen... I've never done that in WPF tho, only WinForms.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
lblName.GetBindingExpression(Label.ForegroundProperty).UpdateTarget();
```

before

```
var foreground = ((Label)grid.Children[0]).Foreground;
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but the Foreground still has the default value.

Comment: It's the first code snippet in my question. 3 lines of xml/xaml.

Comment: It works if you do mainGrid.Children.Add(grid); where mainGrid is the grid located in your MainWindow.xaml. 
Meaning you have to add your "grid" to some control

Comment: I know, but I don't want to do that. It want to get it working in a console application without any UI.

Answer (score 1):

There are automatic `DataContext` change notifications, the binding will update if the necessary conditions are met. One of them is that the control is loaded (`IsLoaded == true`) which is not the case in your code. The control will only load if you add it to the your UI somewhere.

Example test code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid grid = null;
    Action action = () =>
        {
            var foreground = ((Label)grid.Children[0]).Foreground;
            MessageBox.Show(foreground.ToString());

            grid.DataContext = new { Color = Brushes.Green };

            foreground = ((Label)grid.Children[0]).Foreground;
            MessageBox.Show(foreground.ToString());
        };
    grid = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("Stuff/GridOne.xaml", UriKind.Relative)) as Grid;
    if (grid.IsLoaded)
    {
        action();
    }
    else
    {
        grid.Loaded += (s, _) => action();
    }
    // This adds the grid to some StackPanel, if you do not do something like this
    // nothing will happen since the control will not be loaded and thus the event
    // will not fire, etc. 
    ControlStack.Children.Add(grid);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to perform any rendering. But it seems that this is not possible.

Comment: @Daniel: What exactly is the point of having a Grid that is not rendered? Also: You don't need to place in the UI immediately after all, but you can already hook up those procedures to the `Loaded` event.

Comment: The XAML is a template which is used for a reporting engine. It gets rendered to a PDF/SVG but is never displayed directly. I use the XAML file to define the report and wanted to take advantage of bindings and especially ValueConverters.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the onetime binding? remove that, and it should work.

Comment: No, that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Reading from the other comment, that you want to create the grid off screen. maybe this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788731%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `DataContext` in an object, and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, then the binding will update when the property changes, and there's no need to update the binding manually:

```
public class MyDataContext : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private Brush color;
    public Brush Color
    {
        get { return color; }
        set
        {
            color = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Color");
        }
    }

    //implementation of PropertyChanged and RaisePropertyChanged omitted
}
```

and then update it like so:

```
var dc = new MyDataContext();
grid.DataContext = dc;
dc.Color = Brushes.Green; //this will trigger the NotifyPropertyChanged and update the binding
//color should be changed now
var foreground = ((Label)grid.Children[0]).Foreground;
```

Hopefully this helps...

Comment: Thanks, but that approach doesn't work for me. My datacontext is a simple POCO and all properties are set before rendering takes place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a property of a control to be binding to a property of DataContext but want to change the datacontext in runtime, there is a much more simple way to do it.
Create a ContentControl, then use ContentControl.ContentTemplate

```
        <ContentControl Content=something>
            <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Foreground="{Binding Path=Color}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        </ContentControl>
```

Change the Content of the ContentControl instead of changing DataContext of the Label.